# Flutter emulator failed to start

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, flutter-test

I am trying to test my app but it fails with the message "Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554"

I removed .lock files from the avd that I was using

I also tried "File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Clear"

Moreover, I removed the virtual devices and created a new one, I restarted the IDE, but nothing changed

What else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new emulator (work for me)